# Storyboard Autolayout to work like it did in prior versions

Tags: autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I realize its impossible to actually get X-Code to work like it used to, but it used to just work perfect across almost all devices. It knew that when you added a constraint you intended for that constraint to be in proportion to the screen size it was being added to and not a absolute. Is there a way to do this still and not get this horrible effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use equalWidth or equalHeight constraint instead of using the leading and trailing constraint. For example if you want a label have proportional size according to the screen size of the device, let say you want your label to have 60px * 100px on iPhone 6, control-drag the label to the view and tick **Equal Width** and **Equal Height**, then go after the constraint and change the multipler to 60:375 for the width constraint and 100:667 for the height constraint. The size of the label will be exact proportional to the screen size.

Wish can help you.